# RxJava2 - throw exception from subscription's consumer

Tags: java, rx-java2, rx-android

```
  public void testOne() throws IOException {
    throw new IOException();
  }

  public void testTwo() {
    Completable.error(new Exception("Test exception"))
        .subscribe(() -> {}, throwable -> {});
  }

  public void testThree() throws IOException {
    Completable.error(new Exception("Test exception"))
        .subscribe(
            () -> {},
            throwable -> {
              throw new IOException(throwable);
            }
        );
  }
```

First and second methods work perfectly fine. But in case when I want to catch an exception coming from a Completable and re-throw it, I can't:

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.Exception: Test exception
```

I don't fully understand why can't I throw an exception from the subscribe() method? How can I handle this scenario properly?

Comment: In async APIs, generally there is no reason or opportunity the execution could return to the initiating thread just after the `subscribe` call, therefore, throwing exceptions doesn't work. You have to signal it further down in some fashion. In this case, you could try `blockingSubscribe`.

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case using the `blockingGet` and checking if throwable is not null should also work. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by akarnokd, I could use one of blocking methods. In my case I've decided to do it like this:

```
  public void testThree() throws IOException {
    final Throwable throwable = Completable.error(new Exception("Test exception")).blockingGet();
    if (throwable != null) {
      throw new IOException(throwable);
    }
  }
```